# How to communicate between links on the browser and a java program on background service.?

Tags: javascript, jsp

I m trying to develop an Anti-Phishing software. I want get the url which is been clicked on the browser and sent it to an java application which is running as a service in background before it visits the page of the url. I m new to this. I searched for the communication between browser and java in net, but i couldn't get the solution. Please help me, I want to know what are the languages and concepts i need to know to develop it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `ajax` and `javascript` to build asynchronous request.

Look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) for a general description.

Then, you can use a javascript framework like [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) to make easy request.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but Ajax is used to send data to a server right? but i need the url to a java service running behind.

Comment: Yes, but you can 1) Get the url of your link 2) Send it to the server 3) Wait the server response 4) If ok, redirect to url. You also receive data with ajax

Comment: Thank you, can u help me how we can make a java program as a background service